# Pycharm error when adding interpreter, permission denied

Tags: python, pycharm

I get permission denied on pycharm when adding an interpreter. It used to work and suddenly broke not sure what changed. It broke on pycharm 2.7.3 i upgraded to 3.0 but still broken. The interpeted is added but it throws this error. Any information would be useful. I think it might broke after installing virtual enviroments(not sure)

The paths are ok but the packages are empty and the install button is grayed out. Usualy i install through terminal but it would be nice to get the ide fully working anyway.

**Update**

> which python ->/usr/bin/python

**Update 2**
I found that some egg files have different permissions.
When i change the permissions to rw r r (644) they come back to 600 for some reason.

> umask -> 0022

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 02.09.2013 01:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 53 root root 4096 23.09.2013 21:29 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8 02.09.2013 01:06 top_level.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1319 02.09.2013 01:06 PKG-INFO
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    1 02.09.2013 01:06 dependency_links.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 5792 02.09.2013 01:06 SOURCES.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 8666 02.09.2013 01:06 installed-files.txt

drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 31.08.2013 22:28 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 31.08.2013 22:28 ./
-rw------- 1 root root    9 31.08.2013 22:28 top_level.txt
-rw------- 1 root root  563 31.08.2013 22:28 SOURCES.txt
-rw------- 1 root root    3 31.08.2013 22:28 requires.txt
-rw------- 1 root root  425 31.08.2013 22:28 PKG-INFO
-rw------- 1 root root    1 31.08.2013 22:28 not-zip-safe
-rw------- 1 root root    1 31.08.2013 22:28 dependency_links.txt


Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", 
line 2304, in _dep_map return self.__dep_map File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py",
line 2374, in __getattr__ raise AttributeError(attr) AttributeError: 
_Distribution__dep_map During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/foobar/Programming/pycharm3/helpers/packaging_tool.py",
line 115, in main do_list() File "/home/foobar/Programming/pycharm3/helpers/packaging_tool.py",
line 47, in do_list requires = ':'.join([str(x) for x in pkg.requires()]) File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py",
line 2323, in requires dm = self._dep_map File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", 
line 2308, in _dep_map for extra,reqs in split_sections(self._get_metadata(name)): 
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", 
line 2750, in split_sections for line in yield_lines(s): 
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", 
line 2009, in yield_lines for ss in strs: File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", 
line 2337, in _get_metadata for line in self.get_metadata_lines(name): 
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", 
line 1325, in get_metadata_lines return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name)) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", 
line 1322, in get_metadata return self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info,name)).decode("utf-8") 
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", 
line 1426, in _get stream = open(path, 'rb') PermissionError: 
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.1-py3.3.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt'
bpython 0.12 /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bpython-0.12-py3.3.egg 
pygments Pygments 1.6 /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Pygments-1.6-py3.3.egg 
OpenGLContext 2.2.0a2 /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/OpenGLContext-2.2.0a2-py3.3.egg 
Cython 0.19.1 /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Cython-0.19.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg 
docutils 0.11 /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/docutils-0.11-py3.3.egg 
selenium 2.35.0 /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/selenium-2.35.0-py3.3.egg 
numpy 1.7.1 /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/numpy-1.7.1-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg 
matplotlib 1.3.0 /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.0-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg 
python-dateutil:tornado:pyparsing>=1.5.6:nose nose 1.3.0 /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/nose-1.3.0-py3.3.egg 
pyparsing 2.0.1 /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyparsing-2.0.1-py3.3.egg tornado 3.1 
/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado-3.1-py3.3.egg or create new VirtualEnv
```

Comment: It looks like you've somehow convinced PyCharm that your main installation, in /usr, is a virtualenv, so it's trying to install into it without using sudo/PAM/whatever, and therefore getting permissions errors.

Comment: i see i was almost sure it has to do with venv. don't know how i managed to do that let me try mess around and see if i can fix it.

Comment: I've never used that feature of PyCharm before, but the fact that it's clearly failing on files out of your main site-packages, and you said you think it happened since enabling virtual environments, and there's a "or create new VirtualEnv" at the error all point to something in that area…

Comment: Also, did you enable virtual environment support via `virtualenv` from PyPI, or the built-in `venv` from 3.3?

Comment: i did python virtualenv.py foobar. i was following a tutorial so i assued the person knew what he was doing

Comment: appart from that i did /path/to/venv/bin/easy-install package and /path/to/ven/python /path/to/script. nothing more

Comment: ok found something strange with permissions on my os, updated the question

Comment: OK, it looks like my guess was wrong. The problem is finding out why your site-packages aren't world-readable. This is getting more into a platform/distro-specific problem, a method-of-installing-Python problem, and/or a your-particular-shell-environment problem…

Comment: i think it was something with a broken package or so. not exactly sure what caused it, i managed to solve it. i posted the answer. it was very strange it happened after i was messing with venv it might have been just something random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

1. I found out that 1 specific egg (`python_dateutil-2.1-py3.3.egg`) had incorrect permissions(`600`) for not linux users this means only admin can read the file.
2. I changed permissions(to `644`) and re-add the interpreter. The permissions came back to `600` automaticly. Umask is fine(`022`) so i assumed pycharm changed it.
3. I did `sudo pip install --upgrade python-dateutil` and changed the permissions again to `644`.
4. Then it worked. I assume there was something about the pkg that pycharm didn't like.

pip output:

```
sudo   pip install --upgrade python-dateutil
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil in /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.1-py3.3.egg
Downloading/unpacking six from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.4.1.tar.gz#md5=bdbb9e12d3336c198695aa4cf3a61d62 (from python-dateutil)
  Downloading six-1.4.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package six

Installing collected packages: six
  Found existing installation: six 1.3.0
    Uninstalling six:
      Successfully uninstalled six
  Running setup.py install for six

Successfully installed six
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Your experience guided my in the right direction, so thanks. My problem was that my home directory was owned and writable only by root : ) That's where Pycharm wants to put it's helpers...

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this problem after installing Java Development Kit and Eclipse.The way I fixed it was to uninstall the jdk from the control panel and reinstalling Python 3.2 making sure I added the new path name.I also removed the previous PATH variables linked to Python.

Comment: It sounds like your answer is for Windows, but the asker was on some brand of Unix. This answer is not likely to help them, and is also several years late.